# Which visibility modifier is better for @Provides method in @Module class in dagger2

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

Just as the title:
Which visibility modifier is better for Provides method in Module class, package private(default) or public?

And what's the pros and cons for each modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be more of an opinion question. Nonetheless, I think that package private is the modifier you should be using. Dagger only needs the `@Provides` methods to be package private, so there is no point in making them public. I tend to think that the more you can limit the scope of a method, the better.

Comment: Yes, I also think that the package private is the better option. 
But I'm facing the problem that: I want to pass an object (or call it dependency) into a `@Mudole` class's constructor, to avoid passing it in every `@Provides` method, and this dependency is provided by another `@Module` class, these two `@Module` classes are in deferent package, and then I face the hard choices:
1. Making the other `@Module` class's `@Provides` method public;
2. Re-creating the dependency when build the `@Component` object, and pass it in the first `@Module` class's constructor.
Which one is better?

Comment: @Piasy: The way I've done it in the past is to have each `@Provides` method take in the object it needs as an argument. Then Dagger can do all the magic for you. If you really don't want to do that, try using `@Inject` on the constructor of the module. I'm not sure if that works, but it seems like the cleanest option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!